# SQL group by, how to define which record for each group, eg. the latest, is used

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table that stores a `reference` for each `product-identifier`, however there are some duplicate records - ie. a product may have been submitted more than once so has more than one reference. Each record is timestamped with the `updated` column.

I need a query that will only give one (non-empty) reference per `product-identifier` but that crucially will only select the LATEST record for each product.

So if the original table is this:

```
id    updated              product-identifier   reference
------------------------------------------------------------
1     2014-11-10 07:47:02  9876543210123        98043hjdww98324322
2     2014-11-10 07:53:24  9897434243242        89f7e9wew329f080re
3     2014-11-12 10:51:10  9876543210123        48308402jfjewkfwek
4     2014-11-12 12:53:24  9876543210123        89739432bkjfekwjfk
5     2014-11-12 12:55:16  9876543210321        21321hhfioefhewfoe
6     2014-11-13 01:01:10  9897434243242      
7     2014-11-13 01:05:24  9897434243242        1232423jhdksffewfe
```

The query should return just these records:

```
id    updated              product-identifier   reference
------------------------------------------------------------
4     2014-11-12 12:53:24  9876543210123        89739432bkjfekwjfk
5     2014-11-12 12:55:16  9876543210321        21321hhfioefhewfoe
7     2014-11-13 01:05:24  9897434243242        1232423jhdksffewfe
```

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE reference !='' GROUP BY product-identifier ORDER BY updated DESC
```

and this gives only one record for each product, but **not** the latest - it is grouping before sorting.

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this by having a subquery that selects the highest timestamp for each group (product_identfier in your case) and then use that to select the row I want. Like this

```
select * 
  from tablename a
 where a.updated = (select max(updated) 
                      from tablename b
                     where a.product_identifier = b.product_identifier)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain how this is different from, or better than:

`SELECT id,max(updated),product_identifier,reference FROM  tablename GROUP BY product_identifier` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  If you want the latest record, here is a method using `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where not exists (select 1
                  from tablename t2
                  where t2.product_identifier = t.product_identifier and
                        t2.updated > t.updated
                 );
```